# Is it possible to use Jade inheritance with Meteor?

Tags: inheritance, meteor, pug

I use Meteor and Jade in combination, via the [meteor-jade package](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-jade), and would like to make use of Jade's [template inheritance](http://jade-lang.com/reference/inheritance/) support in order to create several similar views. Is this at all possible with meteor-jade?

I tried to write a layout.jade file, and extend it in another template, but the problem is its contents have to be enclosed in a `template` tag, which then gets rendered into the HTML.

## Example Jade files

**layout.jade**

```
//- Doesn't work since Meteor requires content to be in a template tag
.modal.fade(class=modalClass tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby=labelId
    aria-hidden="true")
  .modal-dialog
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        button.close(type="button", data-dismiss="modal", aria-hidden="true") &times;
        h4.modal-title(id=labelId) #{title}
      .modal-body
        p #{message}
      .modal-footer
        button.btn.btn-default.btn-primary(type="button", data-dismiss="modal") OK
```

**messageModal.tpl.jade**

```
extends ./layout.jade
```

Comment: don't guess you figured this out?

Comment: @jaruesink Sadly, no. Haven't tried since.

Comment: Strange that no one has something to say on this.